# Detect incomplete translation files in Qt

Tags: qt, qt-linguist

I want to be able to detect if translations are missing for any language during my release build.

I'm using CMake to build the application and CMake is also running `lupdate` and `lrelease`. In this process I would like to display a warning if some translations are missing in the TS files. As far as I can see `lupdate` and `lrelease` does not allow detection of missing translations, I have checked the output when running the commands with `-help` option. According to the Qt docs:

> Both lupdate and lrelease may be used with TS translation source files
>   which are incomplete. Missing translations will be replaced with the
>   native language phrases at runtime.

This is very fine, but I would really like some indication that the files are incomplete.

Any ideas?